# Printing to the screen kernel basics

Tags: kernel

As a Basic kernel version I am printing to screen with my own build kernel. with the following code I don't see any code being printed on my screen. I am deploying only kernel using 'qemu-system-i386 -kernel kernel.bin' command

Kernel.c

```
    void kmain() {
       volatile short *video = (volatile short *)(0xB8000);
       video[0] = 'h';
    }
```

Comment: If my answer has helped you, indicating that by accepting it would be appreciated. If not, please respond with more information.

Comment: Actually that didnt help .made that change and tested it didnt help

Comment: If I put the equivalent code in my kernel (`mov [0xB8080], word 0x0F68`), I get a letter on the screen. Are you sure that your code is being called?

Comment: Yes, I am sure code is being called I tried via gdb.

Comment: That code should work if the video card is in VGA mode 3 (text mode), and if you are running in a flat memory model. If your kernel is multiboot compatible, you can set flags to request that text mode be enabled by the loader, otherwise the video card may be in some other mode. Can you give more information about how you are compiling the code? (command lines, linker script, other code, etc.)

Comment: Alternatively, you could try poking values onto the screen using gdb, to determine what code is needed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not strong in C, but I do know that the video buffer at `0xB8000` is made of (character, attribute) pairs. It doesn't look like you are writing any attributes, which means that the character is probably being displayed as a black letter on a black background, which you can't see.

What if you add some attributes, something like:

```
video[0] = ((short)'h' | 0x0F00);
```

Those attributes should make it display as a white letter on black background.
For more information about the screen (and other things), see the OSDev Wiki [here](http://wiki.osdev.org/Printing_to_Screen). There is also a list of the colors available [here](http://wiki.osdev.org/Text_UI).